# SQL Server convert varbinary to string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that has a varbinary field like:

0x83838383838372723 .....

I would like to concatenate this varbinary field to a string, for example:

```
SELECT CONCAT('Varbinary value is', varbinary_field)
FROM MyTable
```

I expect the following string:

```
Varbinary value is 0x83838383838372723
```

I need to use concat so how to do it?

Comment: Er... This is tagged as SQL 2008 but CONCAT was introduced in 2012. Also, I believe you're looking for `CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), myBinaryValue, 1)` or something like that. See binary styles [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use the *built-in* function `fn_varbintohexstr`:

```
DECLARE @SomeHexString VARBINARY(MAX)=CAST('This is just some text, which should be a HEX-string' AS VARBINARY(MAX));
SELECT @SomeHexString;

SELECT 'This is concatenated: ' + sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@SomeHexString)
```

This function existed [in 2005 already, but was limited in length](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46910/sys-fn-varbintohexstr-returns-null-if-varbinary-data-is-more-then-2000-as-datale). Should be fine with your 2008 environment...

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work. BTW, it seems the varbinary you posted is not really valid.

```
declare @Bin varbinary(max) = convert(varbinary(max), 'My binary value')

select concat('varbinary value is: ', cast(@Bin as varchar(max)))
```